# Add property from string to Groovy class

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Is it possible to add property dynamically to Groovy class from string?
For example I ask user to insert string, say 'HelloString'
And I add property HelloString to existing Groovy glass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with this.  E.g. you can use [`propertyMissing`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing)

> ```
> class Foo {
>    def storage = [:]
>    def propertyMissing(String name, value) { storage[name] = value }
>    def propertyMissing(String name) { storage[name] }
> }
> def f = new Foo()
> f.foo = "bar"
>
> assertEquals "bar", f.foo
> ```

For existing classes (any class) you can use [`ExpandoMetaClass`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass+-+Properties)

> ```
> class Book {
>   String title
> }
> Book.metaClass.getAuthor << {-> "Stephen King" }
>
> def b = new Book("The Stand")
>
> assert "Stephen King" == b.author
> ```

or by just using the `Expando` class:

```
def d = new Expando()
d."This is some very odd variable, but it works!" = 23
println d."This is some very odd variable, but it works!"
```

or `@Delegate` to a map as storage:

```
class C {
    @Delegate Map<String,Object> expandoStyle = [:]
}
def c = new C()
c."This also" = 42
println c."This also"
```

And this is how you set the property by a var:

```
def userInput = 'This is what the user said'
c."$userInput" = 666
println c."$userInput"
```

Comment: Really comprehensive answer! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

If the property name and the property values are each dynamic, you can do something like this:

```
// these are hardcoded here but could be retrieved dynamically of course...
def dynamicPropertyName = 'someProperty'
def dynamicPropertyValue = 42

// adding the property to java.lang.String, but could be any class...
String.metaClass."${dynamicPropertyName}" =  dynamicPropertyValue


// now all instances of String have a property named "someProperty"
println 'jeff'.someProperty
println 'jeff'['someProperty']
```